# How to add scrollbars in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I want to add scrollbars in my iframe. Below is my code.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"  width="1349px" height="100%" scrolling="auto">

</iframe>
```

I am writing this in Drupal 7. Problem is it doesn't show iframe with scrollbars and border. Earlier I simply set the source without width and height and scrolling options and it showed iframe with scrollbars but after adding width and height,it disappeared.

Thanks

Comment: I have made change to my answer for scroll and border to appear

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`scrolling="yes"` and also `frameborder` aren't valid HTML5 attributes anymore. They can't be found in the list of allowed attributes, see: [W3C: 4.7.6. The iframe element](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element) or [MDN: <iframe>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Use CSS instead:

```
iframe {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 1349px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

But actually all browsers show the scrollbars right away if needed.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/JmwTf/)

Comment: But why this horizontal scrollbar is disabled here?

Comment: @bsm It seems that it's common among all browsers (I didn't test IE actually) that they don't show the scrollbars for an `<iframe>´ if they aren't needed.

Comment: Okay.I am testing it in Firefox.

Comment: @vapcguy Well, actually it does. Tested it using the demo link. Note that that horizontal scrollbar might not be visible, as the example page is responsive and will fit into the iframe. [Try this link instead](http://jsfiddle.net/7jx9fL14/).

Comment: @insertusernamehere Odd - yours works, but please look at mine:  http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/v8oof0g0/  I have a link opening CNN's main page in a modal dialog. The right-side scrollbar appears, but doesn't work on the main contents (I noticed it actually scrolls CNN's right-sidebar menu, if you expand the window height), and there is no horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: The link to w3.org seems to be a dead link. I found this on Mozilla's site which outlines the attributes for `iframe` and what's supported and what not https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @SmurfEkko Good catch. W3C moved the current documentation to *github.io*. I've updated the link accordingly, I also added the MDN link. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

you were missing scrolling="yes" in your code try the following code

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"  width="1349px" height="100%" scrolling="yes">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change scrolling="auto" to **scrolling="yes"** and add **frameborder="1"**

Try the style:

```
iframe {
   border: 1px solid #000 !important;
   overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks..I tried this but still there is disabled horizontal scrollbar and iframe box is without border.

Comment: I have made some changes to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the `scrolling` attribute to

```
scrolling="yes"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. After making this change, it shows disabled horizontal scrollbar also there is no border..

Comment: @DrSatan1, do not enter in filler text. If you're answer is too short try adding a description of what your purposed changes do, which you should do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with Firefox, ie, or edge.

The way i solved my particular issue is removing a class's overflow: auto
and replacing it with the following on the parent of (in my current case) a table

```
class {
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```