# Cursor issue when using iframe in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, iframe, cursor

I am an `iframe`, which is used to display a web page within a web page, on my WordPress site..

The problem is when the cursor is on the external page, which does not have a scrollbar, and I try to scroll down on this page, scrolling is not working at all. However, when the cursor is on my web page, scrolling works just as fine. If I try to go to the content of the page (the frame "external page") and try to scroll down, scrolling is not possible.

However, when I try to scroll down on the side of the main page (my web page), I will see that is working well.

I would like the scrollbar of my page works normally when I try to scroll and my cursor is on the external page.

Here is the code I use:

```
<iframe id="external page" style="overflow: visible;" 
        src="https://mylink.com" name="external page" 
        width="99%" height="1000" frameborder="1" 
        marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" scrolling="no" 
        allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355060/how-to-add-scrollbars-in-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add scrollbars in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355060/how-to-add-scrollbars-in-iframe)

Comment: sounds like you need either the iframe to fill 100% of the visable area OR some kind of javascript that puts focus on the iframe

Comment: You could try to set the overflow on the iframe to "scroll" instead of "visible". I'm not sure if this will resolve the issue, however, it might. You can also try to specify overflow-y: scroll; and overflow-x: visible;